# ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

```
//присваиваем переменной индекс, который равен значению первого элемента
var c = linkedList.ElementAt(linkedList.First.Value);

//добавляем в лист
secondList.AddLast(c);

for(int x = 1; x < linkedList.Count; x++ )
{
    ////присваиваем переменной индекс, который равен значению текущего элемента
    c = linkedList.ElementAt(c);
        secondList.AddLast(c);
}
```

Из-за того, что индекс элементов массива начинается с [0], вылетает *ArgumentOutOfRangeException* (список начинается всегда с 1)

Вопрос, возможно ли в шарпе переопределить первый индекс или решить проблему как-то по-другому?

Comment: какого типа переменные linkedList и secondList?

Comment: _список начинается всегда с 1_ - это откуда такое предположение?

Comment: обе переменные типа LinkedList<int>. Изначально с консоли вводится кол-во элементов обычного массива, потом туда заносятся элементы по порядку и перемешиваются. Затем все копируется в linkedList.  Далее элемент со значением 1 становится в начало списка.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что означает «решить проблему». Вы обращаетесь по индексу, которого нет в контейнере, и это вылетает? Ну так не обращайтесь по такому индексу. Вы используете индекс, отсчитанный от 1, как будто это индекс, отсчитанный от 0, и это вылетает? Ну так не используйте его неправильно, в чём проблема? Или вы не знаете, как превратить индекс, отсчитанный от единицы в индекс, отсчитанный от нуля?

Comment: @Grundy я принудительно задаю значение первого элемента равным 1.

Comment: @cruim, так это же значение, а не индекс

Comment: @Grundy все верно. у меня вопрос, почему кто-то говорит, что индекс в LinkedList<int> начинается с 1. ведь если Console.WriteLine(linkedList.ElementAt(0)); то выведется первый элемент списка(он же нулевой).

Comment: @cruim, например я так понял это по тексту в вопросе

Comment: @cruim спискок - это коллекция, в которой значения доступны по индексу. При этом индексы от содержимого значений не зависят. Списку вообще все равно, какие значерия в нем лежат. От того, что вы куда-то в него положите значение 1 - индексация не поменяется. С таким же успехом вы можете положить туда значение "qqq" - индесация все равно будет идти от 0, а не от "qqq"

Comment: @ PashaPash я в курсе) видимо не совсем однозначно описал задачу, судя по комментариям.

Comment: частично решает проблему.for (int x = 1; x < linkedList.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                ////присваиваем переменной индекс, который равен значению текущего элемента
                if (c == linkedList.Max())
                {
                    c = linkedList.Last.Value;
                    c = linkedList.ElementAt(c);
                    secondList.AddLast(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    c = linkedList.ElementAt(c);
                    secondList.AddLast(c);
                }

            }

Answer (score 0):

Так как, судя по описанию, значения в списке начинаются с 1, то для использования их в качестве индексов в этом списке, нужно просто вычитать единицу при передаче значения в `ElementAt`.

Comment: `ElementAt(k)` для связного списка O(k), так что правильнее было бы не использовать его, а пройтись при помощи `foreach` или чего-то такого.

Comment: @VladD, а чем тут foreach поможет? тут же как я понял как раз в том, чтобы брать элемент по индексу равному текущему _значению_ элемента. То есть за один проход в любом случае не получится, и как я понимаю индексатора у связного списка нет

Comment: Ох, и правда. Теперь я понял. Код ТС пытается эмулировать LinkedList при помощи массива и индексов (в массиве лежит значение + индекс следующего элемента). Но так как ТС не вполне понимает, что делает, он взял в качестве несущей структуры не массив, а уже готовый LinkedList! Что приводит, понятно, к катастрофическому падению производительности. Насчёт foreach вы правы, да.

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется тут проблема в другом. `x` переменная в цикле не играет никакой роли, просто переменная `c` равна первому значению в массиве `linkedList` а оно может быть от `-max int` до `max int`. Допустим у вас размер `linkedList` = 10. А первый элемент `linkedList` (Если он типа int) равен 100, то 100-го элемента в массиве нет, отсюда и `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Answer (score -1):

Индекс элементов начинается с 0 до `linkedList.Count-1`, например 10 элементов, тогда 0..9

```
for(int x = 0; x < linkedList.Count; x++ )
{
    c = linkedList.ElementAt(c);
        secondList.AddLast(c);
}
```

Comment: count - 1 зачем? Просто `< count`

Comment: @Herrgott точно. исправил. спасибо!

Comment: в данном случае не важно с какого числа начинается `x`, эта переменная все равно не используется внутри цикла

Comment: @Grundy уже заметил :)